# Hierarchinal tree using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, tree

```
[
  {
    "lev1": "ELECTRONICS",
    "lev2": "PORTABLE ELECTRONICS",
    "lev3": "MP3 PLAYERS",
    "lev4": "FLASH"
  },
  {
    "lev1": "ELECTRONICS",
    "lev2": "TELEVISIONS",
    "lev3": "TUBE",
    "lev4": null
  },
  {
    "lev1": "ELECTRONICS",
    "lev2": "TELEVISIONS",
    "lev3": "LCD",
    "lev4": null
  },
  {
    "lev1": "ELECTRONICS",
    "lev2": "TELEVISIONS",
    "lev3": "PLASMA",
    "lev4": null
  },
  {
    "lev1": "ELECTRONICS",
    "lev2": "PORTABLE ELECTRONICS",
    "lev3": "CD PLAYERS",
    "lev4": null
  },
  {
    "lev1": "ELECTRONICS",
    "lev2": "PORTABLE ELECTRONICS",
    "lev3": "2 WAY RADIOS",
    "lev4": null
  }
]
```

I have the above json and I want to create hierarchical tree from it.

How to do that?

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: just a tree? in Json? PHP? MYSQL? it really depends on a lot of factors, your question should be much longer (excluding the code)

Comment: That tree is an example tree on [this page](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/), and it has all the code you need, explanations and alternative methods to normal trees.

Comment: i have a table with parent child relationship and i want to form a family tree